# Is there any good tutoria or reference for writing code with Magma?

Tags: gpu

Currently I am trying to use [Magma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) to do matrix operation on GPU, however, I found few documents about it. The only thing I can refer to is its testing program and the online generated document([here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/custom/index.html?lid=126&slid=234)), which is not convenient to use. And the user guide seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=571&p=1758&hilit=matrix+inversion#p1758),  getri and potri are supported.